# Tkinter filedialog window disappears when I hide tkinter main window and click something else than the filedialog

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, filedialog

I have a code that hides the `tkinter` main window and opens a `tkinter.filedialog` window:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import pandas as pd

tkinter.Tk().withdraw() # hide the main window 
excel_file_path = fd.askopenfilename()
if excel_file_path == "":
    quit() # user clicked cancel ---> terminate program execution
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path) 
# process df ...
```

The problem is that when the `askopenfilename()` box is open, if I click something else than the box, for example I click my excel sheet or anything else on the window but the dialog box, the dialog box disappears. The program is still running, but I cannot do anything. `ctrl-C` does not help. The only thing I can do is click `ctrl-alt-del` and kill the process from task manager.

I tried to change `tkinter.Tk().withdraw()` to `tkinter.Tk().iconify()`. This helps and removing `withdraw()` altogether helps as well, but when I do that, the main window is visible.

What I want to do is to hide the main window and stop the dialog box from disappearing. How can I do that?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in my Windows 11 with Python 3.12.1.

Comment: @acw1668 I have the same OS and same Python version. I write my code in VS code. Did you use exactly the same code block that I have in my original post?

Comment: Yes but without the pandas related stuff.

Comment: That is strange. I deleted the pandas stuff but the problem still exists.

Comment: Unable to reproduce (Windows 10, Python 3.11.1). If I click outside the filedialog, the filedialog loses focus but doesn't disappear. If your problem cannot be reproduced by other users on the same OS or environment, it may be related to the Python installation on your machine. Reinstalling may help. Also, use sys.exit() to exit the program instead of quit().